# Windows Forms: DrawImage blitted width and height slightly too small

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm using DrawImage in a Windows Forms C# project to draw sprites at varying sizes. Hspace is just a control that lets you change the horizontal spacing. The output is broadly as I want it except the 4 scaled sprites are all slightly too small: their height and width is off, by 1 pixel on the x2 and x3 scaled ones and by 2 pixels on the x4 and x5 scaled ones.

You can see the output here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jvKZ.png

```
Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filePaths.First(), true);
TextureBrush texture = new TextureBrush(image1);
Graphics formGraphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

formGraphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

int xpos = 0;
for (int sizer = 1; sizer < 6; sizer++){
    formGraphics.DrawImage(image1, xpos, 40, image1.Width * sizer, image1.Height * sizer);
    xpos +=  (int)hspace.Value+  (image1.Width * sizer);
    }

formGraphics.Dispose();
```

Comment: Counting pixels from that screenshot looks like a very unattractive task.  Play with formGraphics.PixelOffsetMode, I assume you like Half better.

Comment: You don't have to count the pixels. If you zoom in (although you can still notice it anyway probably) you will see the top and left edges of the object are thinner than the other edges.

Comment: The PixelOffsetMode tip works though, thanks!

Comment: You may want to write the working code as an answer, maybe with images..